How to check if a file or folder is available for moving?
Before moving a group of folders and files, I want to check that all files and folders are not locked for moving.
They may be locked by an external process, they may be running, or perhaps an external process has also locked the folder.
What is the best way to perform such a check?
I am thinking about the LockFile or LockFileEx functions.
If you try to impose exclusive access on a file, and if LockFile returns False, then someone has already locked the file or run it. Right?

Anything can happen anytime - even you as a user can change file(system) permissions/delete/rename/move/rewrite while the move is in progress. Just like the drive can dismount/die/crash at any moment. Or the destination can run out of space/become unavailable before your moving is complete. You just have to expect that things can fail.

You generally cannot - directory contents may become locked between you do a check and start the operation. As for locking - to lock a file, you need to open it, and having the file opened will prevent its parent directory from moving.
